# web3.eth.getAccounts returns only limited addresses

Tags: javascript, ethereum, web3js

In my website, there are more than 4700+ addresses currently. When I try to get all accounts using 'web3.eth.getAccounts' it only returns 3360 addresses. I don't know why this happens. For the remaining addresses which are not listed in getAccounts, I have tried 'getBalance' to check if address is valid or not, but it returns expected balance.

```
web3.eth.getBlock('latest',function(blockErr,getBlock) {
  // console.log(getBlock);
  web3.eth.getGasPrice(function(priceErr, getGasPrice) {
  // console.log(getGasPrice);
    web3.eth.getAccounts(function(accountsErr, accounts) {
      console.log(accounts.length) // 3360+
    })
  })
})
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you using a private network or connecting to main/testnet? Does your server/app connect to a cluster of nodes? `getAccounts()` will only retrieve accounts that were created on the node connected to. `getBalance()` will work regardless of which node the account was created on. Also, if the node you're connected to is not fully synced, you may be missing some accounts.

Comment: Hi @Adam, Recently I had some issues with ETH server. So I restored with old keystore backup. Will this be a problem ?

Comment: Yes, that is likely to be the reason you're not seeing all of your accounts. The accounts are still valid and can be used so long as you can import all of your private keys and haven't lost the passwords.